# C# DirectSound volume control

Tags: c#, volume, directsound

I Make the Voice Chat but I can't control Volume and Pan. When I control the Volume, It is not working.

```
playbackBuffer = new SecondaryBuffer(playbackBufferDescription, device);
//playbackBuffer.Volume = 0; // -1000 ~ 0
//playbackBuffer.Pan = 0;
playbackBuffer.Write(0, byteDecodedData, LockFlag.None);
playbackBuffer.Play(0, BufferPlayFlags.Default);
```

How to do?

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Comment: when i set the voulume, i can't hear voice

Comment: 0 is the *minimum* volume, -1000 is the *maximum* value, see [SecondaryBuffer.Volume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms817348.aspx): "The return value is between Volume.Min and Volume.Max. These values are defined as 0 and -10,000, respectively. The value Volume.Max represents the original, unadjusted volume of the sound. The value Volume.Min indicates an audio volume attenuated by 100 dB, which, for practical purposes, is silence."

Comment: when i set the volume value(0), i can't hear the voice. i don't know why.

Comment: "0 is the **minimum** volume" - what happens when it is set to -1000?

Comment: oh my.... i set Volume value and run. it is fall out in catch{}

Comment: 0 represents the maximum volume (see [Volume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms811468.aspx)) with no attenuation. So if you want your buffer unchanged, providing 0 for the volume is correct.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Then what is up with the other documentation? :<

Comment: i find the solution. i set playbackBufferDescription.ControlVolume = true;